# Wordpress / Civi - How to Hide All Menus

Tags: menu

Install is latest WP w/Civi plugin. We would like to hide top menus from end users based on roles and use links in the Dashboard instead for limited functions. I've read postings regarding making changes in Drupal permissions but hosting in Wordpress. I've also seen suggestions of modifying the Civi navigation.tpl file.

Any suggestions for a Wordpress install? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install the plugin User Role Editor https://www.role-editor.com/ Then in WP under *Users* you will see *User Role Editor*. Set permissions according to your needs. You can also find Dashboard plugins that will allow you to control what the dashboard looks like based on user roles. I use ABD Dashboard Widget. The downside of this one is that you can only use it to specially control 1 user role. But that is all I need. I use it to simplify/control our contributors dashboards.

Comment: Thanks Carl! I'll have to check out your recommendations.